# floated list items cause bullets/numbers to disappear on webkit

Tags: css, html, webkit

My css:

```
ul, ol {
  margin:0 0 1em 0;
}
ul:after, ol:after, ul:before, ol:before {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
li {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
```

My html is any normal list structure

Works as expected on Firefox and appears as normal bulleted or ordered list.

However, on Webkit browsers Chrome/Safari the indentation is as expected but list styles are absent.

Solutions discussed here ( [Show unordered list inline, but keep the bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399/show-unordered-list-inline-but-keep-the-bullets) ) do not apply to me, since I need to solve this for both unordered and ordered lists. IE7, is however not a requirement (IE8+ is).

The floated list items is odd, I know, but it is a requirement for the text selection UI I am building.

Please note while this works in JSFiddle, a pure HTML/CSS page demonstrates this behaviour:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      ul, ol {
        margin:0 0 1em 0;
      }
      ul:after, ol:after, ul:before, ol:before {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
      li {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li>two eggplants, not too fat</li>
      <li>red sauce, hopefully from your kitchen</li>
      <li>fresh mozzarella</li>
      <li>basil</li>
      <li>breadcrumbs, or stale/dried bread to make them</li>
      <li>a couple of eggs for breading</li>
      <li>parmigiana cheese for breading</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS appears to work in Chrome.. what am I missing? http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Khd2F/

Comment: This is bizarre... it works independently, but not within a div#words which is the general container for text. #words has no other styles affecting lists at all and I've commented out all other styles in general for testing. I've also put a list outside of #words and it renders correctly. I can't imagine what is going on here.

Comment: No... this works on jsfiddle in chrome but only there.. is this some sort of Quirks mode style thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Most of my day later... ALWAYS USE A DTD

Also works with 4.01 strict.

Sad

Comment: Awesome. Had this same issue with Safari and wkhtmltopdf, and this was the only solution which made our styles work correctly.