# What is the simplest way to display unordered list items inline and also keep the bullets in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have a similar issue to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399/how-to-dispay-unordered-list-inline-with-bullets). I have an unordered list where the `li` tag has the `display:inline` property. Now the list items are being displayed one after the other on the same line, but the bullets are missing. I'd like to know the simplest way to have my elements show up both inline and with bullets.

In [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer) the top answer says it's correct to create a new question if the technology changed. The question linked is older than Chrome, with the top answers expected to account for IE7. There have been changes in web standards since then as well. Consequently, I think the technology has changed significantly enough to warrant another question. It is likely enough that the answer to this question is different from what was posted on the previous question that even if it happens to be there some confirmation is required.

Comment: Did you take the time to read *all* the answers in that link? there is some answers using CSS grid which is something new, there is also solution with floats

Comment: While its OK to post a new question if the technology *has* changed, it's not just because the technology *might have* changed. You should in your new question identify what precisely has changed that *actually* invalidates the old answer(s). Age of answer is not a reason.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, I read all the answers. But I didn't try each answer. Regardless, I saw the CSS grid answer and I don't believe it answers my question. It seems unnecessarily complicated, as I don't want columns, I want inline text, so I'd have to figure out a way to change the grid to do that.

Comment: @Alohci The old answers aren't necessarily invalid. I'm sure many will still work, most notably the accepted answer. But I believe the change in technology means there is a better answer for Chrome than for IE7. I think the given answers so far demonstrate that.

Comment: CSS grid is one example to show that the question is still relevant since this is the newest feature. There is also the use of float and inline and other suggestion that are still up to date.

Comment: @Alohci The question is relevant, hence why I'm asking it. The problem is that the answers are not relevant to the technology I'm working with. It seems as though the only appropriate way to get a relevant answer would be to put up a bounty, correct?

Comment: A bounty or not, if you want a different answer then you need explain why the answers currently available don't meet your requirements. So you don't want grid, because that gets you columns, fair enough. What's wrong with the float answer? If you just want *additional* answers, then yes putting up a bounty is the way to go.

Comment: @Alohci Dang, ok. I will write another question explaining the problems with all the other answers....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the unordered list element, use flexbox. On each of the list items, use margin: auto.

Here's an example:

```
<ul style="display: flex;">

<li style="margin: auto" > item 1 </li>
<li style="margin: auto" > item 2 </li>
</ul>
```